What came of the Trump campaign's complaint to the FEC that Harris 'stole' (or at least illegally received) Biden's funding?
The Trump campaign complained to the FEC in late July that

Kamala Harris is seeking to perpetrate a USD 91.5 million heist of Joe Biden's leftover campaign cash a brazen money grab that would constitute the single largest excessive contribution and biggest violation in the history of the Federal Election Campaign Act of 1971, as amended.

Has the FEC ruled on this complaint since then?
Additionally (if they haven't decided), the initial reporting was that the FEC "declined to comment, citing the agency’s policy on not discussing enforcement matters". Can they do this forever, or do they have to give some formal answer, at the least to the complainant, at some point?

I mean as both of your cited articles have told:

It’s unlikely that the commission would take any action until well after Election Day, given its slow pace of resolving enforcement questions. - CNN


It's unlikely that the commission would take any action until well after Election Day, given its slow pace of resolving enforcement questions, CNN reported. -Business Standard

Which seems to be well in line with how long FEC decisions take. According to How to file a complaint with the FEC (fec.gov):



Stage
Number of Days




Complaint received



Complaint notification
5 days


Response to complaint
15 days


RTB findings



Investigation



Pre-probable cause conciliation
60 days


General Counsel's brief



Response to General Counsel's brief
15 days


Probable cause to believe



Probable cause to believe conciliation
30-90 days


Disposition




So yeah given that the reports were on 24th of July it would take way after the election before a decision is to be expected, as just parts of the process that have legal deadlines would add up to more than the remaining days and I'm not sure not an expert on how long the other parts of investigation might take but apparently CNN floated the idea of:

“I don’t think most campaign finance lawyers believe that this is a best reading of the law,” Rick Hasen, an election law expert at UCLA’s law school, told CNN on Tuesday of the Trump campaign’s argument. But, he added, “that doesn’t mean it can’t get tied up in FEC proceedings for years.”

Also with respect to "no comments". Well they are not only allowed but legally required to do that:

To protect the interests of those involved in a complaint, the law requires that any Commission action on a MUR [=matter under review] be kept strictly confidential until the case is resolved. These provisions do not, however, prevent a complainant or respondent from disclosing the substance of the complaint itself or the response to that complaint or from engaging in conduct that leads to the publication of information contained in the complaint. Nevertheless, information about a Commission notification of findings or about a Commission investigation may not be disclosed, unless the respondent waives the right to confidentiality in writing.
Because the public has the right to know the outcome of any enforcement proceeding, a redacted case file is made available to the public on the Commission’s website when the Commission’s vote to close the file becomes effective, which is 30 days (or the next business day if the 30th day falls on a weekend or a holiday) after the Commission Secretary certifies the Commission’s vote to close the case file.

From what you can find that might be an interesting case for legal academia, because that's kind of a first and apparently Harris can largely make the case that she was already on the same ticket with Biden and already entitled to that money for her campaign as vice-president. Though whether that money would need to be given back to donors to be invested to her again or whether that money would need to go to the party or whether her campaign committee is the same or a different entity and whatnot, might actually be interesting questions.
According to the liberal think tank Brennan Center for Justice, it could even be to Harris' advantage to have a new committee as apparently running on a shared ticket poses caps on financing, while running two doubles that.
Also the largest sum of the money was already transferred to Harris legally, so it's not that she is without money, far from it, it's "just" about those $91 million, so even if she would be unable to use that, it might still be more of a PR battle than an actual problem for her. And given that it is a first, the case might also be dismissed or considered unreviewable. So yeah that's probably an interesting case but one not pressing in this election.

"It’s unlikely that the commission would take any action until well after Election Day" Trump, infamously pushing to delay all his legal woes until after the election, could claim Harris is copying him.

The time for the FEC to send their first letter on 'probable cause' is just 60 days though (although the FEC notes that extensions are possible there too). So we could hear something before the election. I suspect the fact that correspondence was sent would be leaked to the press.

Likewise if they close the investigation at that stage, they'd have to notify the complainant, who has 60 more days to appeal in the DC circuit court. @Schwern: yeah, the fine print on FEC's page says they can actually vote time extensions at least for the first of those deadlines, i.e. to decide whether or not there's even probable cause.

Do Republicans and Trump have any standing? Or just donors?

@gnasher729 What do you mean? Afaik the question with campaign financing is a) whether donations exceed legal limits to prevent large donors from taking political influence (though that has been watered down) and b) how campaigns are allowed to use money attributed to them. So in that case does giving money to candidate A mean candidate B of the same party can take that money or is that false advertisement as you bought one product and got another, though that is about donors not really something that goes to the detriment of the opposition, right?

@haxor789: My understanding is that prior to Biden's withdrawal, any money to the Biden/Harris campaign could be arbitrarily divided among the following purposes: (1) Ads and events promoting Biden; (2) Ads and events promoting Harris; (3) Ads and events promoting both.  Such funds may not be usable for e.g. campaign events that only promote Harris' VP pick, but that limitation would only apply to money specifically given to the "Biden/Harris" campaign.

@supercat As said, this could be a legit interesting question, even though it's likely only raised as PR distraction and not likely to be resolved in time. Like you could for example argue that the Biden/Harris campaign is it's own legal entity that persists but changed members and priority. Or you could argue that Harris as the remaining member can spend that money as she see fits, with regards to personal use regulations: https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/making-disbursements/personal-use/ Where supporting a VP is part of her campaign and wouldn't happen irrespective of it.

@supercat It's also kind of interesting that this wasn't really evaluated prior to this, given that both Biden and Trump ... are old. Like seriously the chance of one of them dropping out or even dying prior to the election has always been non-zero so that something like that could happen was always an option. Also given that Harris was already on that ticket and eligible for that money makes her claim a lot more substantial than if an entirely new candidate and VP would have been picked who were unrelated to the former and ran with different staff and agenda for example.

@haxor789: I would expect that Harris would find enough things to spend money on that are purely for advancing her own interests, rather than those of Tim Walz, to use up all the funds that were raised by the Biden/Harris organization.  This is far less crooked than the appointment of Lara Trump to head the RNC, at the expense of all non-MAGA Republicans.

@supercat: wrt the "crooked appointment" are you complaining about nepotism or an RNC head demanding ideologically purity?  Because those are almost completely orthogonal (an unrelated chair could demand purity, and a relative could govern a "big tent") and a purity test, however lamentable, is not anywhere near the "crooked" end of the political spectrum

@BenVoigt: Lara Trump has stated her intention to have the RNC focus solely on the reelection of Donald Trump.  It would seem unlikely that a party chair who has publicly stated such intentions would impartially evaluate what uses of party funds would best serve the interests of Republican voters.

@gnasher729 Standing isn't relevant here.  The issue in question would be a violation of federal law if true, and the government always has standing to prosecute that. Those filing complaints are basically just whistleblowers (though not necessarily in the strictly legal sense, with laws protecting them), trying to bring the government's attention to alleged violations.

The FEC will allow its people to make comment once the matter is fully closed and any appeals are spent.
The claim, however, is spurious. Kamala Harris is uniquely situated to lawfully utilize the funds leftover from Biden's campaign because she was part of that ticket, and so may direct its operations.
Both US News and The Hill agree that the law here allows Harris to command the use of those funds so long as she remains part of the campaign ticket - even if another nominee had risen but taken her on as running mate.
If Harris had not secured the nomination, she'd be forced to pay back any of that money spent between the date Biden dropped out and the nomination process completed, but because she's the nominee no violation has occurred.
So the FEC will not find any violation.  They likely will wait until after the election to say so, because once someone lodges a complaint there's due process that has to take place and it'll be more than two months.

I would like to think that the FEC would not find any violation, but the way things work these days, I would not be shocked if they did eventually decide there was one, in a 3-2 vote (with 1 abstention/empty D seat).

@Bobson: I wonder if they can resign and make FEC lose quorum like it happened before.

Just reiterate that giving the money to Kamala doesn't seem to be controversial.
legitimate of unused political contributions once a candidate ends their pursuit of office includes donating the funds, without limitations to another candidate or even to the national party.

52 U.S. Code § 30114 - Use of contributed amounts for certain purposes
(a)Permitted uses
(4)for transfers, without limitation, to a national, State, or local committee of a political party;


Your answer says candidate but your quote says committee.

@BenVoigt Candidate and Committee the same with regard to fundraising at the national level in the U.S.  A committee is required for federal candidates raise and spend money by FCC rules. Federal candidates must designate a principal campaign committee, This campaign committee takes in contributions and makes expenditures for the candidate’s campaign..  It's just how campaigns work at the federal level.

But that's a campaign committee and the quote specifically says a party committee.  Might be important, might not be any distinction at all.
